# python regex extract string between characters

Tags: python, regex

I have a string:

```
x = "abc/xyz/foo/bar/foobar.mp3"
```

How to extract foobar out of it?

I have done it in this way:

```
import re
re.search(r'\/[a-z]+.mp3', x)
```

Although, I do not know how to extract the matched string without '.' and without '.mp3'.

I do not want to do Python splits, rplist, partition etc. as it adds extra functions. I want it to be as simple and short as possible.

EDIT:

1. Yes, it is a path.
2. I do not know the length of the path.
3. As mentioned, I do not want to use splits.

Comment: `print(os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(x)))`?

Comment: (it's a duplicate assume it's a file path. Given the `.mp3` I'd think that it is)

Comment: x.split("/")[-1].split(".")[0]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Match non-slashes, then lookahead for `\.mp3$`:

```
re.search(r'[^/]+(?=\.mp3$)', x)
```

Make sure to escape the `.` with a backslash, else it will match any character.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this

```
[a-z]+(?=\.mp3$)
```

- `[a-z]+` - matches alphabets one or more time
- `(?=\.mp3$)` - positive lookahead to check match must be followed by `.mp3` and end of line

[**Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/x9Ggo5/1/)